# Passing variables between forms using a button

Tags: c#, winforms

I'd like to know how to pass, let's say an integer, from form1 to form2.

I tried to do that through a button that would open form2, but the event button click didn't recognize the integer... What should I do?

In form1 I have integer x, and I want that when I click on button1, form2 would open up with x value in a label.

If there's a way to pass the info without the button (then I could use the button just to open form2) that would be great as well.

Answer (score 2):

you can use second form constructor.

```
    private int input;
    public Form2(int input)
    {
        this.input = input;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

when you create an object , you can pass your var(int in here):

```
        int myvar=911;
        Form2 tmp = new Form2(myvar);
        tmp.Show();
```

now you can use that private variable in form2:

```
lbl.Text=input.toString();
```

---

in Form1:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 tmp = new Form2(911);
        tmp.Show();
    }
```

and in Form2:

```
    public Form2(int input)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        label1.Text = input.ToString();
    }
```

send your code for solve this problem.i can't find out why it doesn't recognize your vars without your codes!

Comment: That's what I tried to do, but I want it to open frm2 from a button click.and I cannot pass my variables from frm1 to that event( it doesn't rexognize them)

Answer (score 1):

In your code have a variable accessible by both forms. For example create a new Namespace and add a `public static class FormData` with a `public static int Value` inside.

```
namespace GlobalVariables
{
  public static class FormData
  {
    public static int Value { get; set; }
  }
}
```

Then from both of your forms you can access the said variable (and modify it) with `GlobalVariables.FormData.Value`. Here I made it a property, but you can do pretty much whatever you want with it.

Comment: That's a great idea, though I use my self made class team which has an array of players.. Also self made. It tells me I cannot make a sstatic array... So I guess I'll have to pass that. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to passing the value by Form2 constructor, you can create a property that sets the label value, e.g.

Form2

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public int XValue{
        set{
            label1.Text = value.ToString(); 
        }
    }
}
```

Form1

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private int x = 10;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 form2 = new Form2();
        form2.XValue = x;
        form2.Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: or simply `new Form2(){XValue = x}.Show();`

Comment: @L.B this isn't codegolf :P

Comment: The thing is I change the value of x in form1_load. It's weird, if I do what you did and change the value in form_load, its working. But when I do it with my "team" class, its not working. I'll check that further...